# can matching or matchit Rpackage be used in conducting case-control study?

Tags: r

I'd like to conduct a nested case-control study by using R to do individual matching (1:N).
But either Mathcing or MatchIt in R are all conducted for treatment group and control group matching.
Is there any other proper package in R to do individual mathcing according to their outcome events rather than treatment or exposure events?

Comment: Why can't you just set the outcome as the treatment/grouping variable in `MatchIt`?

Comment: I have tried, but the statistician asked me if it was suitable to treat the outcome as the dependent variable both in the matchit algorithm and the logistic regression model.  I just wanted to use the matchit function to match cases with normal participants. Statisticians have raised this question, but have not explained what is inappropriate to do so。

Comment: Well, the outcome isn't the dependent variable in the matching algorithm; it's the grouping variable. If you are trying to match two groups, you have to tell the matching software what the two groups are. The way you do that is by putting the grouping variable on the left-hand side of the formula supplied to `matchit()`. `matchit()` doesn't know or care what the interpretation of the grouping variable is (i.e., whether it's interpreted as a treatment or as an outcome).